# &#xA; appearing in web.config file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-config, ankhsvn

I'm seeing a lot of weird escaped characters typically 
 in my web.config appearing.  Has anyone ever seen them? what causes them? and is it safe to leave in the web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that some editor inserts those when the file has a non-matching EOL character combination. Windows uses CRLF, and if only a single CR or LF is found (UNIX and Macintosh use those AFAIR) this might be what the editor created to maintain a high fidelity of the text data. But they should be interpreted as whitespace and therefore not hurt you.

See also the [Wikipedia article on newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).